# Save filter and show it on homepage

Tags: usability, mobile, mobile-application, filter

I'm working on enterprise app that would be an one stop place for a few departments to store their dashboards and reports( or maybe different file types )

The Homepage shows the files listed on their date added. Every file contains tags that show the Product, Region and Business they are associated with.

One of the groups, whose app is a menu item, has an independent Dashboard and Report section that list their files respectively. Below is the home page

[image]

This is the navigation view showing Dashboard and Report sections.
[image]

The user can apply filters to find Dashboards specific to a Business, Product or Region or all 3. The applied filters are shown on the top.

[image]

I want provide a mechanism that will save these filters and can be shown on the homepage as saved filter with some kind of visualization.

[image]

**How can I save the applied filters and show it on the home page. How can the user on and off the filter?**

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it. I understand that "Home" is the main (first) list. But what is the "Dashboard" page? A single dashboard? A dashboard construction page? What is the Type/Month switch doing? And why do you want to save filters on the home page? Should that be a filter applicable to all items on the home page? Maybe you'll get more responses if you reformulate the question.

Comment: So imagine this to be Hub for different departments to come and add their content. Dashboard is one of the navigation items in menu if the app specific to one of the departments. I have updated the question with Navigation view.

Comment: Nodnin, thanks for the edit. You say you want to "save [the] filters and [they] can be shown on the homepage" - but you probably don't want to show the filter alone, but rather an (existing) dashboard with the filter applied, do you? The filter appear on the Dashboard page of your drafts, that's why I ask. Do you want to filter data an one (or all dashboards), or do you want to filter the list of Dashboards?

Answer (score 1):

What do you think of using a colored status bar, like GPS or phonecalls do on iOS. By using this bar, you could allow the user to edit the filter by taping on it, or provide a simple "remove" button to discard it.

[image: Example]

Comment: Interesting idea. I'm considering it.